# How to rsync with a private key?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, rsync, file-transfer, azure

I'm trying to rsync from my MacOS machine to an Ubuntu server that's running on Windows Azure. To ssh to it, I have to do the following:

```
 $ ssh -i  myPrivateKey.key -p 22 me@me.cloudapp.net
```

I think the key file might be an X509 public key, if that helps (sorry, I'm no sysadmin). Anyway, I can ssh successfully with the above command.

Now I'd like to rsync files to the remote server. Do I need to supply the `.key` file as an option somehow?

A normal rsync command fails:

```
$ sudo rsync -avz -e my/file me@me.cloudapp.net:/my/path
    rsync: Failed to exec my/file: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/pipe.c(86) [receiver=2.6.9]
    rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [receiver]
    rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c(452) [receiver=2.6.9]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command fails not because of wrong keys, but because **you're telling rsync to run `my/file` instead of `ssh`** (by using the `-e` option, which picks up the word following it). Remove the `-e` option first.

Since `rsync` normally uses `ssh` to connect, you can configure *both* to always use a particular key for connecting to cloudapp. For example, put this at the top of your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host me.cloudapp.net
    Username me
    IdentityFile ~/my-cloudapp-key.key
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

The `Username me` part will also let you skip adding `me@` when using ssh or rsync. Plain `rsync -avz my/file me.cloudapp.net:/my/path` will work.

---

Note: SSH keys are not X.509 certificates; they're just plain RSA or ECDSA keypairs without any additional information.

Comment: On Ubuntu it seems to be `User` instead of `Username`

Comment: If you need a different port than 22 you can add a line with `Port 8023`. Alternatively you will have to add `--rsh='ssh -p8023'` directly to the command line.

Comment: On `macOS` too, it's `User` instead of `Username`, else I get `Bad configuration option: username`.

Comment: Most time saving tip ever! Esp. with the comments about Ubuntu and macOS. Thx all.